# How to assert an imported Class in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I need to import a nonexistent class (which would be exist when actually being used) in a typescript ES6 module. I hope it can be extended in this way:

/typings/events.d.ts:

```js
export interface IEvents {
  $on(event: string, listener: () => {}): void;
  $once(event: string, listener: () => {}): void;
  $off(event: string, listener: () => {}): void;
  $emit(event: string): void;
}
```

main.ts

```js
import { IEvents } from './typings/events.d.ts';
// @ts-ignore：ignore temporarily nonexistent module
import Events from '../../common/base/Events';

Events as IEvents; //Something like it...just to assert this class

class Monitor extends Events implements IEvents {
  constructor() {
    super();
    //So I can invoke this.$on, this.$off..etc directly.
  }
}
```

However, I always get the error message "Type 'Monitor' is missing the following properties from type 'IEvents': $on, $once, $off, $emit".

Is there any proper way to implement it? Thanks in advance! :D

EDIT:

I tried redeclaring Events variable after I import it (see [code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=2&ssc=46&pln=2&pc=1#code/PTAEAEBcGcFoEsDmA7A9gJwKYCh4FsAHDSUAUQDdNkZQAzdVPUAcmkc2AHcALTLYACapM0asEwAPeNEjMA3NlzU%20tAIYBjTKACSFKjQDe2UKAAkqZAApMlagC5QM9PGSIANKAA20yFT4PLAEpQAF4APlADAF9Ah3JUeAEFE3NkTWtbSAcnF3cvHz90AODwyJi4hKTjM1RaWgz9bMhnVw9vGULi0Ijo2NB4xOSzTDx4SAb7R2bcvoGqqMUBTHVPVSxQFdVoaDJMnfwCTxH9Hd09yOqUiwmsqZa89t9kf1Ag7rLZyqGrtMwbpvubQKzyKrxKPXK-S%20lxqdX%20d1yQI6IK6pV6FUGMNMIzG8Jyrk%20mIW2E221AAFkLGMMKBJE8BDs9NR9oQjngTjomYYYeoLE4AK7qSAYN5GEzi8XQfkEPhBOQShXimESkAAZVQOg2qmQoBc8QA1lpINxpAA6VIeY1m8x1U2mzCQdSgATwLBCzwAT1NMIWxKAA)), but it doesnt work. The import line would be discarded after redeclaration..

Answer (score 1):

When you have code written somewhere else but you want TypeScript to know about, you need to [`declare` its type definitions somewhere](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/by-example.html).  Often you put these in their own dedicated library files, but you can use do inline declarations as well.

For example, you could declare it as a `class`, but you need to declare its property/methods also:

```
declare class Events implements IEvents {
    $on(event: string, listener: () => {}): void;
    $once(event: string, listener: () => {}): void;
    $off(event: string, listener: () => {}): void;
    $emit(event: string): void;
}
```

Or you can declare it is a type and a value, where the type corresponds to the instance side of the class, and the value represents the static side including the constructor.  This is often done in standard libraries, where you will see something like a `Foo` type and `FooConstructor` type, and a variable called `Foo` of the type `FooConstructor`.  (e.g., for `Array` you have [`interface Array<T> {...}`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.6.3/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1205) for the instance side, [`interface ArrayConstructor`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.6.3/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1357) for the static side, and [`declare var Array: ArrayConstructor;`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.6.3/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1368) to show that there's an object named `Array` that acts as a constructor).  Here's how you might do it for `Events`:

```
interface Events extends IEvents { }
declare const Events: new () => IEvents;
```

Either of those would work for you.  Hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgSQFEA3YFAZzgG8AoOeuAEgiQAphSUAuOcmKZAHMANHAA2CPmTQ9WASjgBeAHzUAvnJ7EICACYBuOg2ZJc7TjB58BSEeMmokMuPKWqqGrToNH6zdOjmZJa8-EKiElJOULIKKuqacNp6hgxMwAC2CDBB3KE2gonJPmo0NEiYGcDkYDh4ACLA2GKYUMAAwi3klLS+cLpNLW1wzZjdcCTBlAgZYGKZUwSTFNR9aSa5Idbh9lHOrvEeRd6pacYsZhzBVmG2EQ7SMS5x7p5JJ2vnAZs3Bfd7TwOr2OKU+fky2R++SEIJ8aVKfVG4wAsixstA4KBHLpKMsYNNZvMqisiBYemCRixrABXbAwaCuWhnZm8algNDyfQss4UtIAej5AGUIAQRpgkIgkNoANZ4GAAC0kADoTKIFcr-OglUrgDBsP0EG06WIAJ5KimleFlBEVKo1OpwRqjNrtKnwXppZCoDAOvGULFkHFLMnUOCWhgDZ14bBuiZknhOADuzzcwamhkRXUoqKQ6KgmJA2NxIZmcwWJL9q25MaQNLpDIUTO5DHIbI5clOzbgAuFouw4slMrlivIKpYapHY4C2t1+t0hqaMFN5u54fopTUQA)

Comment: Hi jcalz I really appreciate your explicit answer! Thx a lot! However, my situation is a little bit knotty here..I need to import an non-existent variable first `import Events from 'some/where/doesnt/exist';`, so I cant redecalre it later or this import line would be discarded...I know there must be something unusual happens in my code!

Comment: Can you put your declarations in a file at `some/where/doesnt/exist/index.d.ts` in your dev environment?

Comment: Or anywhere that the compiler can [find them](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html)?

Comment: Yes, I can put the interface/class of Events in `some/where/index.d.ts` and it works globally. But I need to comment out the line `import Events from 'some/where/doesnt/exist.js'` or this Events(=== undefined) would override the globalwide Events interface. The point is the compiler cant find 'some/where/doesnt/exist.js'.. 

Comment: The compiler shouldn't need to find the .js file, it only needs to find the .d.ts file.  Only the runtime environment should care about the js, which presumably will be there.  Can you edit your code into a [mcve] so that I can see what you're seeing in my own IDE?  Or maybe post a stackblitz/codesandbox link in addition which demonstrates the issue (btw your playground link is broken)?  I can't reproduce it.

Comment: Sorry it took quite a long time to reply..:P I finally figured it out and really grateful for all your help! Wish you a very good day..! 